# WPF - MVVM not setting Path Style when binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have my tab item declared as below:

```
  <TabItem >
                <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="pricefiles:ConfigureViewModel">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Path Style="{Binding StandardEnabled}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Standard" Margin="5" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Standard:StandardView />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
```

And then in my view model i have:

```
    private Style _standardEnabled;

    public Style StandardEnabled
    {
        get { return _standardEnabled; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _standardEnabled, value); }
    }

 public ConfigureViewModel(SYSTEM_Account account)
    {
        try
        {
            Account = account;
            StandardEnabled = (Style) Application.Current.FindResource("HeadersIcon");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

    }
```

The style is in a resource dictionary declared as:

```
    <Style x:Key="HeadersIcon" TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0,13.333001L35.555001,13.333001 35.555001,33.778223C35.555001,35.250969,34.36089,36.445002,32.88818,36.445002L2.666523,36.445002C1.1938604,36.445002,2.4359167E-07,35.250969,0,33.778223z M3.2485678,6.19415L3.2485678,8.0274701 22.415489,8.0274701 22.415489,6.19415z M3.2485678,2.6108398L3.2485678,4.44415 22.415489,4.44415 22.415489,2.6108398z M2.666523,0L32.88818,0C34.36089,0,35.555001,1.19415,35.555001,2.6666899L35.555001,10.222 0,10.222 0,2.6666899C2.4359167E-07,1.19415,1.1938603,0,2.666523,0z" />
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF000000"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"></Setter>
</Style>
```

When ever this code fires I can see the resource (style) within the StandardEnabled property however it then doesn't get databound to the Path.

I'm going to want to databind the with different resources depending on different circumstances.

EDIT:

The view/viewmodel is initialised when the user presses a button on a parent window:

```
try
{
    var tmpVm = new ConfigureViewModel(SystemAccount);
    var tmp = new ConfigureView(tmpVm);
    tmp.ShowDialog();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

To initialize the data context:

```
public ConfigureView(ConfigureViewModel configureViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = configureViewModel;
}
```

Comment: Is this code snippet complete? Are you actually instantiating a `ConfigureViewModel` somewhere and assigning it to the `TabItem.Header` property?

Comment: Why are you doing a `SetProperty()` in a view model? It's a bit of too-close coupling there, IMHO. Just set the private variable and move on... I'm wondering whether this will fix your problem.

Comment: The SetProperty calls OnPropertyChange and also validates the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your problem. The issue is that you're defining a `HeaderTemplate` that targets `ConfigureViewModel`, but not explicitly setting the content of the `Header` to an object of that type.

Because of how you are setting your `DataContext`, there is actually no need to define a template. You can just define the controls normally, and the bindings will work as expected. You can replace your `TabItem.HeaderTemplate` with the following XAML

```xaml
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Path Style="{Binding StandardEnabled}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="Standard" Margin="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

If you wanted to keep the header template, you could expose a property of type `ConfigureViewModel`, and then bind the tab item's header to it. It might require some minor refactoring, but it may be what you're going for. The following is an example.

```xaml
<TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="pricefiles:ConfigureViewModel">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Path Style="{Binding StandardEnabled}"/>
               <TextBlock Text="Standard" Margin="5" />
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
<TabItem.Header = "{Binding MyConfigureViewModel}" />
```

With the first solution, you're explicitly defining what the header should look like, and binding its properties directly to the `DataContext`. With the second solution, you're saying I want to bind the content of my header directly to something on the `DataContext`. Then using a template to define how that object should be displayed. Hope that makes the distinction clear.